# Possible to solve for a common base number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This may be a little low-brow for this forum, but I'm trying to figure out what the common base number set is between two other sets of numbers.  Here's the situation: I have received quotes from two vendors for a list of products that they sell, and the prices they have quoted are:

```
             Vendor 1's Price        Vendor 2's Price
Item #1      $9.76                    $9.12
Item #2      $15.60                   $14.56
Item #3      $9.76                    $9.12
Item #4      $15.60                   $14.56
Item #5      $9.76                    $9.12
```

Each vendor is taking a certain "list price" and each is applying its own margin.  Is there a way to figure out what the "list price" is that these two vendors are working off of?

Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to find a true base price; there are a variety of values it could be.  For instance, item 2 could have a base price of $\$10.40$; this would give a $50\%$ markup for Vendor 1, and a $40\%$ markup for Vendor 2.  This corresponds roughly (but, only roughly!) to a price for item 1 as $\$6.51$.  On the other hand, you could have item 2 as $\$5.20$, which is a $200\%$ markup for Vendor 1, and a $180\%$ markup for Vendor 2.  Indeed, any base price you pick, you can get a markup percentage that works for each vendor and can be back-applied (roughly) to the other item.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem there are, essentially, $4$ unknown quantities -- the base prices of the first two individual items (call those $P_1, P_2$) and the markup rates of the two vendors (call those $r_1, r_2$).  The first two rows of the table above give you $4$ equations; namely, $r_1 P_1 = 9.76$,  $r_2 P_1 = 9.12$,  $r_1 P_2 = 15.6$ and $r_2 P_2 = 14.56$.  Going into this, you might expect that 4 equations ought to be enough information to determine the values of 4 unknowns.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work out so well.  From the first pair of equations you can conclude that $r_1 / r_2 \approx 1.0702$ and from the second pair of equations you can conclude that $r_1 / r_2 \approx 1.0714$.  So the hypothesis that each vendor has a "constant margin" that he or she uses for all items -- in other words, that vendor 1 uses the same rate $r_1$ for both item 1 and item 2 -- is not supported by the data.

In response to this you might say, "Well, we're rounding to the nearest penny anyway, so I am okay with some slight error due to rounding.  Let's just say that $r_1/r_2 = 1.07$, that's probably close enough."  Okay -- but now the problem is that the remaining equations now contain insufficient information; all you have left is that

$$r_2 P_1 = 9.12$$
$$r_2 P_2 = 14.56$$

Three unknowns, but only two surviving equations.  From this you can conclude that the *ratios* of the two items' list prices is $14.56/9.12 \approx 1.60$ -- but you probably knew that already.  The actual list prices are not determined by the data.  (On the other hand, if you knew just *one* of the list prices, you could use this to find the other list price and the two markup rates.)